# SQL query exclude a certain value from same column same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a student table called ACADEMICDETAIL that looks something like this: (ADW stands for Add/Drop Wait and can have these values 'A' =add, 'D' =drop, 'W' =wait)

```
PeopleID  |  ADW  | Class  | Term  |  Year
  1234        A      Math   Spring    2017
  1234        D     Spanish Spring    2017
  1234        A      Biol    Fall     2016
  1234        A      Engl    Fall     2016
  0001        D      Engl   Spring    2017
  0001        D      Math   Spring    2017
  0001        D      Biol   Spring    2017
  5601        W      Math   Spring    2017
  2300        D      Biol   Spring    2017
  2300        A      Engl    Fall     2016
```

My (bad) query looks something like this:

```
SELECT distinct PeopleId 
FROM ACADEMICDETAIL
WHERE 
Term = 'Spring' and 
Year = '2017' and
ADW = 'D'
```

I need to only pull students who have dropped all classes for specific year/term. If some were dropped but others are still added, I don't need those students in results.

So the result I need to get:

```
 PeopleID
   0001 
   2300
```

Reality with my bad query:

```
 PeopleID
   0001 
   2300
   1234
```

Any tips? I don't want the 1234 student to show up because that student has both adds and drops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PeopleID
FROM ACADEMICDETAIL 
WHERE ADW = 'D' 
AND Term = 'Spring'
AND Year = '2017'
AND Peopleid NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT PeopleId 
FROM ACADEMICDETAIL
WHERE Term = 'Spring'
AND Year = '2017'
AND ADW IN ('A' , 'W'))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Think `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT year, term PeopleId 
FROM ACADEMICDETAIL
GROUP BY year, term, PeopleId
HAVING MIN(ADW) = 'D' and MAX(ADW) = 'D';
```

This selects all `term`/year`combinations.  You can of course use a`WHERE` clause to limit to only one or a few.

Comment: That helped distinct students by ID but still doesn't eliminate any Adds per student. In other words, I am still getting students that have Adds and Drops. I am trying to lookup all student who only have Drops. Hope that helps! Thanks!

Comment: @Nestalnaj . . . This cannot return students who have Adds.  Note the `HAVING` clause.  The minimum and maximum values of `ADW` are equal and are `'D'`.  Hence, only `'D'`s.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think the result you are getting are correct. Base on your query there is actually 3 distinct row meet your condition.

Comment: Hi @Nestalna your query and result is correct. Check my last answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for each PeopleID if there is any other AWD happened to exist for that particular ID.

```
SELECT distinct PeopleId 
FROM ACADEMICDETAIL AS A 
WHERE 
Term = 'Spring' and  Year = '2017' and
((Select count (*) from ACADEMICDETAIL as A1 where AWD = 'D' and A1.PeopleID = A.PeopleID) - 
(Select count (*) from ACADEMICDETAIL as A2 where AWD = 'A' and A2.PeopleID = A.PeopleID) ) >= 0
```

EDIT1 :

I create the table, inserted the data in and ran the query. 
You can see the results [HERE](http://rextester.com/FEHZH58307)

Comment: Great idea but it still returns the people with some adds and some drops. I am looking for people that have only drops, no adds, no waits. Thanks tho!!

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't it have returned the student 2300 as well because he/she also had a single Drop in that year/term?

Comment: Added a check on the Where clause to make sure the number of adds doesn't exceed the drops. I don't know what exactly 'Wait' means though.

Comment: Was it what you were looking for?

Comment: Kind of but somehow in production it is still returning some student with Adds. Because in production we have scenarios where there are more Adds than Drops and vice versa. I am still trying to figure out a good way to get only students that have all drops and no adds.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you distinct your data. You will get actually 3 distinct value. In short your script and result is corret

Comment: I know that it is correct, but it isn't what I am looking for. I am looking for a way to modify my query to get the desired result. My query is missing something to make sure only students with all Drops for specific year/term appear in results. Hope that helps!

Comment: Then tell me what condition are you trying to do?

Comment: I got what are you trying to do. Haha sorry. What you are trying to do that is you want only to see the result where PEOPLEID does not have a ADW = 'A' right?

Comment: Correct - where ADW is not A or W, it should only return D. :)

Answer (score 0):

try the solution below

`-- to display 2017 Drop only
select distinct PeopleID from ACADEMICDETAIL  t1
where adw = 'D' and year = 2017
and not exists (select 1 from ACADEMICDETAIL  t2 where t1.year = t2.year and t1.adw <> t2.ADW and t1.PeopleID = t2.PeopleID)`

`-- to display all Drop years
select distinct PeopleID,Year from ACADEMICDETAIL  t1
where adw = 'D'
and not exists (select 1 from ACADEMICDETAIL  t2 where t1.year = t2.year and t1.adw <> t2.ADW and t1.PeopleID = t2.PeopleID)`